# Place holder not showing/ input disable on FireFox, (Chrome and IE works)

Tags: html

Here is the [Contact Form](http://tema2.innovacionesweb.info/contact.html) it's really weird you can input the text nor see the placeholder, I've checked the code and can't see what's wrong with it, also the input it's disable.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The padding on your input is too big and the input can't take all the place it want. Remove your `padding: 29px;` and your inputs works fine.

You can check it with Firebug. The input got a padding of 29px but a height of 0.

Comment: Thanks that was it, i feel stupid. It's weird Chrome doesn't seem to have a problem with the padding.